# Создать список сотрудников(ФИО,должность,з/п).Вводится информация про сотрудников(через input),выводится через таблицу

Tags: javascript, input, dom, table

Вводится информация про сотрудников(через input),выводится через таблицу,затем найти у кого з/п больше 30000 и найти их сумму(всех у кого больше 30000)

```
      <label> ФИО <input type="text" id="workersNames" /> </label><br />
      <hr />
      <label>Должность <input type="text" id="workersPlace" /></label><br />
      <hr />
      <label>Заработная плата <input type="text" id="workersMoney" /></label
      ><br />
      <hr />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Получить таблицу"
        onclick="getTable()"
      /><br />
      <hr />
      <table id="table" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Фамилия,имя,отчество</th>
          <th>Должность</th>
          <th>Заработная плата</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="workersTable"></div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Подсчитать суммарную з/п сотрудников(у кого больше 30000)"
          onclick="getWorkersResult()"
        /><br />
        <hr />
        Всего= <span id="sumWorkers"></span>
      </label>
    </div>
```

```
      function getTable() {
        let works_table = document.createElement("table");
        works_table.id = "works_table";
        let row = document.createElement("tr");
        let works_count1 = document.createElement("td");
        let works_count2 = document.createElement("td");
        let works_count3 = document.createElement("td");
        works_count1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("workersNames").value;
        works_count2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("workersPlace").value;
        works_count3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("workersMoney").value;
        row.appendChild(works_count1);
        row.appendChild(works_count2);
        row.appendChild(works_count3);
        table.children[0].appendChild(row);
      }
      function getWorkersResult() {
        let inputs = document.getElementById("workersMoney").value;
        let s = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
          for (let i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (works_count3 > 30000) {
              s + average[i].value;
            }
          }
        }
        let average = s / inputs.length;
        document.getElementById("sumWorkers").innerText = average.toFixed(2);
      }
```

Comment: В чем вопрос то?

Comment: функция getWorkersResult-не работает

Comment: Не работает  хотя бы потому что нельзя из одной функции получить доступ к переменной, объявленной в другой функции.

Comment: тогда через var или const чтоли?

Comment: Надо бегать по созданной таблице, и там обрабатывать значения. Переменные, с помощью которых таблица создавалась, тут вообще уже не при делах.

Comment: тут функция что если нажимаешь получаешь- новый tr страницы и ты можешь нажать сколько хочешь раз

Comment: @Maksym И что? Сколько строк на данный момент заведено, столько и надо проверить. А еще, что за average[i].value? такой массив нигде не объявлялся, насколько могу видеть.

Comment: ``` function getWorkersResult() {
        let inputs = document.getElementById("workersMoney").value;
        let s = 0;
        for (let i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
          if (works_count3 > 3000) {
            s + inputs[i].value;
          }
        }
        let average = s / inputs.length;
        document.getElementById("sumWorkers").innerText = s.toFixed(2);
      }

Comment: такой вариант не работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так должно выглядеть:

```js
function getTable() {
  let works_table = document.createElement("table");
  works_table.id = "works_table";
  let row = document.createElement("tr");
  let works_count1 = document.createElement("td");
  let works_count2 = document.createElement("td");
  let works_count3 = document.createElement("td");
  works_count1.innerHTML = document.getElementById("workersNames").value;
  works_count2.innerHTML = document.getElementById("workersPlace").value;
  works_count3.innerHTML = document.getElementById("workersMoney").value;
  row.appendChild(works_count1);
  row.appendChild(works_count2);
  row.appendChild(works_count3);
  table.children[0].appendChild(row);
}

function getWorkersResult() {
  let s = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
      if (table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML > 30000) {
        s += +table.rows[i].cells[2].innerHTML;
      }
  }
  document.getElementById("sumWorkers").innerText = s;
}
```

```html
<label> ФИО <input type="text" id="workersNames" /> </label><br />
<hr />
<label>Должность <input type="text" id="workersPlace" /></label><br />
<hr />
<label>Заработная плата <input type="text" id="workersMoney" /></label
      ><br />
      <hr />
      <input
        type="button"
        value="Получить таблицу"
        onclick="getTable()"
      /><br />
      <hr />
      <table id="table" border="1">
        <tr>
          <th>Фамилия,имя,отчество</th>
          <th>Должность</th>
          <th>Заработная плата</th>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <div id="workersTable"></div>
    <br />
    <hr />
    <div>
      <label>
        <input
          type="button"
          value="Подсчитать суммарную з/п сотрудников(у кого больше 30000)"
          onclick="getWorkersResult()"
        /><br />
        <hr />
        Всего= <span id="sumWorkers"></span>
      </label>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо большое